# What can we say about two immersed submanifolds if their intersection is open in one of them?

Tags: differential-topology, submanifold

Suppose $N_1,N_2\subseteq M$ are two immersed submanifolds of $M$,and $i_1:N_1\rightarrow M$,$ i_2:N_2\rightarrow M$ are the inclusion maps respectivly.Suppose $i_1(N_1)\cap i_2(N_2) \subseteq M$ is an open subset of $i_1(N_1)$, Then for any  $p\in i_1(N_1)\cap i_2(N_2)$, is the statment $T_pi_1(N_1)\subseteq T_pi_2(N_2)$  right?
The original qustion I wonder is that if the intersection of two submanifold $N_1\cap N_2$ is an open set in one of them, w.l.o.g in $N_1$, then is the intersection a submanifold of the other one, i.e. is $N_1 \cap N_2$ a submanifold of $N_2$?
Actually ,this question rise from the foliation geometry. It seems that I'm lost in some kind of routine arguments about immersed submanifold/regular submanifold.

Comment: No, the statement may be false for immersed — but not embedded — submanifolds. Try the usual figure 8 example.

Comment: You should spell out your definition of an immersed manifold. Maybe you simply mean a leaf of a smooth foliation?

Comment: @MoisheKohan We just suppose $N_1$ is a leaf, while it is done when both are leaves.Futhermore, I just send a e-mail to the author about this question(I came up with it while reading books), and he replied that this conclusion requires that the inclusion should be continous.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, I have asked the original author about this question, and he stated that the inclusion should be contionus to make the statement correct. Thx!

Comment: With the clarification that $i_1(N_1)$ is a leaf, the claim indeed holds.